# How is appium inspector able to make interactive image from screenshot and page source

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, python-appium, appium-inspector

I am trying to understand how exactly is the appium inspector (webview) able to show an interactive phone screem that i can click button on or move to other screens with, as I see that the calls that is makes to the appium server are just getting the screenshots/rectangle/pagesource etc.

I mean how does it recreate the entire app functionality from a screenshot and also match each element to its respective page source?